# run jquery code only if window scroll position is eqal to 0

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements, scrolltop, scroll-position

I'm trying to write a code that will only works if the scroll position of my window is at 0, using If statement. once someone scrolled the page, the code should not work anymore.

when mouseenter my div .slideshow_2, the page should scroll from 75px, and when mouseleave, scroll back from 75px... but only if my window scroll position is at zero.

I have troubles to define the window scroll position, to check if it's at 0, and with my if condition.

here is my code :

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){

    $('.slideshow_2').mouseenter(function(){
        $("html , body").animate({ scrollTop: 75 }, 500)
    });

    $('.slideshow_2').mouseleave(function(){
        $("html , body").animate({ scrollTop: -75 }, 500);
    });
}
```

my condition is : if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0), I guess this is suppose to check that the page has not been scrolled yet, but there's something I'm doing wrong...

here is a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/uynrhr1c/

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the condition inside the handlers:

```
 $('.slideshow_2').mouseenter(function(){
   if($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
      $("html , body").animate({ scrollTop: 75 }, 500)
   }
 });
  $('.slideshow_2').mouseleave(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == 0)
    $("html , body").animate({ scrollTop: -75 }, 500);
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s9vh10z4/)**

Comment: thanks a lot @Milind Anantwar ! it solved my problem ! I've been able just with this correction to sort a bigger jquery code ! thanks a lot